# Sprite doesn't move in the right direction, in Java 2D game

Tags: java, swing, sprite, game-engine

Working on a Java 2D game.

A sprite is supposed to move in a specific angel, set by pressing left and right keys, and the up arrow key is pushed.

It doesn't move in the angle I want it to move. It moves in an angle that seems to be different in 90 degress. What's wrong?

Relevant methods of `Thing` class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Thing {

    Image image;
    int width,height;
    double x,y,dx,dy,angle;

    public Thing(){

        image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("image.png")).getImage();
        width = image.getWidth(null);
        height = image.getHeight(null);

        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;

        angle=90;

        x = 250;
        y = 250;

    }
    public void move(){
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)angle-=5;
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)angle+=5;
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_UP){

            dy = 5 * Math.sin(angle);
            dx = 5 * Math.sin(90-angle);

        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            setDY(0);
            setDX(0);
        }

    }

}
```

Relevant methods of Board class:

```
package learningMovement;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    Thing t;

    Timer timer;

    public Board(){
        timer = new Timer(10,this);
        t = new Thing();
        setFocusable(true);
        timer.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(t.getAngle()),t.getX()+(t.getWidth()/2),t.getY()+(t.getHeight()/2));
        g2d.drawImage(t.getImage(),(int)t.getX(),(int)t.getY(),this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        t.move();
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)t.keyPressed(e);
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)t.keyPressed(e);
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_UP)t.keyPressed(e);

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)t.keyReleased(e);
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)t.keyReleased(e);
        if(key==KeyEvent.VK_UP)t.keyReleased(e);

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is that:

```
        dy = 5 * Math.sin(angle);
        dx = 5 * Math.sin(90-angle);
```

when it should be:

```
        dy = 5 * Math.sin(angle);
        dx = 5 * Math.cos(angle);
```

Also like HAL9000 said don't forget to convert to radians.

Answer (score 1):

Your `angle` is in degrees, then

```
Math.sin(angle);
```

Should become

```
Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
```

since argument of sin must be expressed in radians.